# Error 13 Mismatch - For Loop Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Button53_Click()

Dim rowsvalue As Integer
Dim rowsnum As Integer

rowsvalue = Sheet1.Range("C38").Value
rowsnum = Math.Round(rowsvalue / 20, 1)

k = 0

For Counter = 16 To 46
    Worksheets("Single L Angle").Cells("F", Counter).Value = rowsnum * k
    k = k + 1
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

I cant figure this out, I am trying to make an VB code that takes the value from cell "C38", divides it by 20 and then pastes those values in cells F16 -> F36. So far everything is fine, but when it comes to:

```
Worksheets("Single L Angle").Cells("F", Counter).Value = rowsnum * k
```

I keep getting Mismatch 13 Errors.

Comment: Try to always have "option explicit" as the first line in your modules, that's a good help, and I can see you surely don't have it activated, since k is not declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Worksheets("Single L Angle").Cells(Counter,6) = rowsnum * k
```

Or

```
Worksheets("Single L Angle").range("F" & format(counter)).Value = rowsnum * k
```

Answer (score 1):

The .Cells() Method takes a Row and a Column as an integer. You cannot pass it a string like "A2". If you want to use it to access a cell, use the row and column number of that cell.

E.g: Select cell "A2":

```
Cells(1,2).Select
```

So in your case you want:

```
Worksheets("Single L Angle").Cells(Counter,6).Value = rowsnum * k
```

Since F is the 6th letter. You can use this generically to loop over a block of cells by nesting loops.

Alternatively you could use the Range() method as described by MattHead93.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Counter = 16 To 46
    Worksheets("Single L Angle").Range("F" & Counter).Value = rowsnum * k
    k = k + 1
Next Counter
```

Does this work any better?